# email image as attachment in swift 3

Tags: swift, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an image as attachment in email but the part below  keeps getting an error of "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional" and showing "(NSData) imageData = variable not available>"

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!)! as NSData
mailComposeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "image")
```

My generated imageView is showing on the view controller correctly.

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: (transformImage))
```

I checked some of the related answers but so far they are not helpful. Could someone enlighten me what I did was wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to be type NSData? Opposed to type Data?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
guard let theImage = myImageView.image else {return}
guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage) else {return}
mailComposeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "image")
```

Comment: Why combine a `guard` with a force-unwrap? The whole point of a `guard` is to avoid force-unwrapping.

Comment: I just did it because he explicitly set the image above but yes you are right it is not the best way to do it. I just adjusted my code.

Comment: It doesn't error any more but my device doesn't attach the image in the email either... How should I fix this?